# zf2 Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException

Tags: exception, service, zend-framework2

I spent half day to resolve this issue with no success.

I'm doing a setup in EC2, centos 6/64 bit. LAMP installed. On another hosting, my zf2 solution it work fine, so I've searched issue in php modules installed also (list at the end).

This error happen when zf2 try to get an instance of my custom service, also with wasabi mail.

\zend\config\application.config.php

```
'config_glob_paths'    => array(
        './config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
    ),
```

\zend\config\autoload\global.php

```
     'service_manager' => array(
     'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',

        'Zend\CustomLogger' => function ($sm) {
            $auth = $sm->get('zfcuser_auth_service');

            $customLogger = new \Application\Service\CustomLogger(
                    $sm->get('Request'),
                    $sm->get('ZendLog'),
                    new \Zend\Session\SessionManager(),
                    $auth->getIdentity(), // $user
                    $sm->get('Mail'));

            return $customLogger;
        },
```

controller

```
<?php 
namespace Foo\Controller;
    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
    use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
    use MyProject\Proxies\__CG__\OtherProject\Proxies\__CG__\stdClass;

    class FooController extends AbstractActionController
    {
        protected $customLogger;

        private function getCustomLogger()
        {
            if (null === $this->customLogger) {
                $this->customLogger = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\CustomLogger');
            }
            return $this->customLogger;
        }

        public function indexAction()
        {
            $this->getCustomLogger();

            $this->customLogger->controllerLog("ENTER IN Foo\Controller\FooController\index", "info");


            // .... other code
        }
    }
```

Error

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException
File:
/var/www/solutions/mysolution/zend/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:930
Message:
An exception was raised while creating "Zend\CustomLogger"; no instance returned
```

PHP modules installed

```
bz2.so       curl.so  fileinfo.so  iconv.so  mbstring.so        mysqlnd.so      pdo_sqlite.so  shmop.so      sqlite3.so  sysvshm.so    xmlreader.so  xsl.so
calendar.so  dom.so   ftp.so       intl.so   mysqlnd_mysqli.so  pdo_mysqlnd.so  phar.so        simplexml.so  sysvmsg.so  tokenizer.so  xml.so        zip.so
ctype.so     exif.so  gettext.so   json.so   mysqlnd_mysql.so   pdo.so          posix.so       sockets.so    sysvsem.so  wddx.so       xmlwriter.so
```

Extension enabled in PHP ini

```
extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/php_bz2.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/php_curl.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/php_fileinfo.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/php_gd2.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/php_intl.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/php_mbstring.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/php_mysql.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/php_mysqli.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/php_openssl.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/php_pdo_mysql.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/php_soap.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/php_xmlrpc.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/php_xsl.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So simple solution... permission on log directory and some others directory are wrong. Restore the correct permissione, user and group on directory (e.g. data/logs, data/cache...)

Comment: You may accept your own asnwer when you found out the solution by yourself :)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, but stackoverflow says: "You can accept your own answer tomorrow" ;)